# Did Apple violate OCP back when they released iOS 7

Tags: ios, solid, open-close

If I remember correctly, back when iOS 7 was released, there were a couple of issues regarding the public API of certain classes which implementation was completely changed. The following is an example of what I mean:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) 
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
else
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
```

In this specific example, prior to iOS 7, the correct way to change the color of the navigation bar was through the use of `setTintColor`. Once iOS 7 was out, not only a new method, `setBarTintColor` was created for the same purpose, but also, instead of deprecating the previous one, the behavior was modified, causing the breakage of multiple source codes (thus the need of using a conditional `if-else` to runtime-check the current version and call the right method).

Does this counts as a violation of the Open/Closed Principle?

Comment: I don't know if that's the principle it breaks but I can tell you that if Scott Forstall and Steve Jobs were still running the show, such an arbitrary API decision would not have been made.

Comment: There is a well known quote "rules are meant to be broken" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my 3 y/o question by saying that OCP principle has nothing to do with API changes, but abstraction patterns when designing classes.

Comment: Classes themselves have an API.

Comment: And Apple is under no obligation to follow *any* of the SOLID principles.